# How to update Tomcat Web application?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an application, that is deployed to Tomcat as `war` file. I need to be able to update some resources of that application, like files with configurations, maybe classes and stuff.

If I understand correctly, if I replace those files within the directory, to which Tomcat extrcted `war`, at the next start up they wil be rewritten with contents of my `war` file. Maybe, I got this wrong?

I thought about deleting `war` prior to the update, but that seems like a stupid way to go.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Update**
I read here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server that the war overwrites the directory when it's "newer". What does that mean? What does Tomcat compare, Date Modified or Date Created or smth else?

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of reproducible and stable builds -- don't. Either re-release your app or store config outside of webapp base.

Comment: True, re-release, dont develop on the production environment.

Comment: The thing is, we are developing for guys who will have VERY bad internet connection during exploitation, and it's crucial to update JUST the XML files, and not the whole application

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @SMSk, store outside of the webapp base.

Comment: @gipinani, it does. It fact, it even tells how to do it reliably.